# FileNotFoundException when trying to open gzipped xml file

Tags: android, xml, gzip, filenotfoundexception

So, I was trying out this tutorial:
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/android-xml-adventure-parsing-xml-using-xpath/
and it worked just fine. I tried to change the code to work for a gzipped file:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
GZIPInputStream gz = new GZIPInputStream(is);
InputSource inputSrc = new InputSource(gz);
```

But the first line throws "java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/raw/data.xml.gz".
I also tried cleaning the project and putting the file in the asset folder and opening it with the asset manager, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please post your code or at least logcat?

Comment: Have you investigated whether gzipping your resources/assets gives results in a smaller filesize at all? After all, .apk files are already "zipped" (deflated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of extension(s) of the file. Rename it to something like `data_xml_gz` and refer like this:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data_xml_gz);
```